Things didn't work out the way I expected them to (had expected them to?)

"Things didn't work out the way I expected them to" or "Things didn't work out the way I'd expected them to"

"He made me say so many things I never thought I’d say" or "He made me say so many things I'd never thought I’d say"


I really want to use the Past Perfect in the examples above, but I have a feeling that the Past Simple might sound better.

I (BrE) would use the past perfect. The 'expecting' and 'thinking' happened before the unexpected outcome.

I (AmE) would use simple past. Americans tend not to use perfect tenses very much.

@Barmar  I would use the past perfect (AmE) when writing but depending on who I was talking to, maybe the simple past or the past perfect. There's a bit of code-switching.

"I really want to use the past perfect." Why? To me (NZEng) the past simple seems more... simple. Past perfect is not wrong, but often not necessary, because the context makes the order of events clear.

As commented, both simple past and past perfect are fine.   Why do you really want to use the past perfect since the sequence of events is clear and the simpler one works?
